# Node js app on EC2 instance - domain name

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using an EC2 instance for the first time, I have a micro instance with my node app running using pm2

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
// Serve Static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.listen(PORT);
console.log('%d App listening on %d', process.pid, PORT);
```

So this will run of port 3000 (is this ok?) . So i can go to `mypublicip:3000` and see my app running.

What I want to do though is go to my domain name `mydomainname.co.uk` and render the site. Domain name was purchased thorough 123 reg.

I have setup Elastic IP already, but unsure where to go from here.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few steps you'll need to follow to do what you're asking.   The first thing you need to do is associate your domain name with your EC2 instance.

To do that, you can either just point your A record in 123-reg to that elastic IP, or (and I recommend this) point your domain's nameservers at a hosted zone you create in Route 53 on AWS.  The procedure for doing the latter is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html).

Once that's done, and the TTL has expired (meaning that the DNS servers have had a chance to update their values), you can test that your domain name is set up right by trying to ssh `your-username@your-domain.co.uk` vice using the public IP that you likely have been using.

After that, or while waiting for that TTL to expire, you should check your EC2 instance's security configuration to make sure port 80 is open (since I'm assuming you don't yet want to bother with an SSL certificate install).

If you really want to run your node app at this point, using pm2, you'll next need to setup Authbind to allow the pm2 user to start a process listening on a restricted port.  From the command line:

```
$ sudo apt-get install authbind
$ sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
$ sudo chown %user% /etc/authbind/byport/80
$ sudo chmod 755 /etc/authbind/byport/80
$ authbind --deep pm2 update
```

Then add to your .bashrc file:

```
alias pm2='authbind --deep pm2'
```

---

Ok, so the above should get you to what you asked in your question.  I have a few notes, however.

1) Please do not follow my last instruction on Authbind. It's a really, really bad habit to get into to let non-root users (even at a controlled level) start tasks on port 80.  Just install and configure nginx as a reverse proxy for your app. It's the right way to do it and it's not that hard.  [This article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps) is dated, but covers a lot of really useful ground and I still go back to it for reference.

2) I mentioned using Route 53. This is for three reasons. First, it's easier to have one place for all your config stuff (your AWS console) rather than two (AWS + reg-123). Second, I've never used reg-123, but Route 53 it's easier to use than most domain sellers DNS settings web apps. Third, it goes a bit further than most and lets you do things like setup poor man's load balancing and other rules, which are useful later in your application's lifecycle.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for a temporary solution, Then you can start your server on port `80` if you are using `http` or `443` if you are using `https` and open this port in security groups. Now you can access your website at `mydomainname.co.uk` instead of `mydomainname.co.uk:3000`.

If you are setting up a app that'll be used by everyone then the method described above is not recommended, In this case you should use nginx reverse proxy or use port forwarding and point the 3000 port on that instance to 80.

Note that If you are using port 80 then on Linux, You'll need to do `sudo npm start` instead of the usual `npm start` to start your server because 1-1024 ports are called administrative ports and you can only use those ports using superuser/root permissions.

This is the reason I suggest you to use port forwarding or nginx reverse proxy in production environment, Because without these methods you'll running your app with super user permissions which can cause serious damage if something goes wrong, Also there might be some security concerns but I don't know what exactly.

Links:

1. [Setting up Nodejs in production environment](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04)